# Cannot find method of executable jar when trying to call in Mirth Connect

Tags: java, executable-jar, mirth

I am using Mirth connect 3.12 and I am uploading my executable jar in customs-lib folder and restarting the Mirth. When I upload jar files with no dependencies and plugin with simple Print functionality I am able to call the method present in the jar file inside the Mirth Connect and operate via following commands:

var obj = new Packages.packagename.classname.method_name;

logger.info(res);

***But when I use an executable jar file with plugins which is compiled in IntelliJ and upload that jar file in Mirth and run the following command in Mirth Script
var obj = new Packages.packagename.classname.method_name;***

I get the following message

[2022-07-22 03:26:15,176]  ERROR  (com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil:522): Error executing Preprocessor script from channel: 15388747-57e4-46f7-bb0e-7da2d2c0ccbd

com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: SOURCE CODE:

```
          207: logger.info('Ended this -' + myCRC);208: 209: try{

          210: 211: /*212: var xyz = new java.io.File('\\\\WVMQTMCEDIAP01').getAbsolutePath();213: logger.info('Started -'+xyz);214: if(new java.io.File(xyz).exists()){215:

          logger.info('I am xyz available');216: }LINE NUMBER:

          212DETAILS:

          TypeError: Cannot find function fileTransfer in object com.alpha.Smb@797b980d.

          at 15388747-57e4-46f7-bb0e-7da2d2c0ccbd_Preprocessor:212 (doScript)

          at 15388747-57e4-46f7-bb0e-7da2d2c0ccbd_Preprocessor:310

          at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executeScript(JavaScriptUtil.java:547)

          at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executePreprocessorScripts(JavaScriptUtil.java:216)

          at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptPreprocessor$JavaScriptPreProcessorTask.doCall(JavaScriptPreprocessor.java:103)

          at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)

          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message. Also, how are you trying to run it? Command line?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have posted the error logs. I am uploading the executable jar file in Mirth customs-lib folder and using below command in Script tab inside Mirth to run it 
    
var obj = new Packages.packagename.classname.method_name;

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get a file using an absolute path, but I have to wonder if that file is in fact a resource of the jar file, and so not a file and if so, then must be obtained as a resource.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not giving enough information. What is a `com.alpha.Smb`? It seems you are trying to call a `fileTransfer` method on an instance of that class, and the method does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the file bearing the fileTransfer function is not coming in with the JAR file or is wrongly referenced in the second/intelliJ compilation. Try using relative references to class paths in the Java code you are compiling. Otherwise try granting full control on the custom-lib folder to the user running the Mirth connect service.